# One Page links with #

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, themes

This is a question about a One Page website (WordPress theme: OnePress). The page has different sections. We also added a blog. When we are on the homepage and we click a section in the menu, the URL stays www.mypage.com. When we are on the blog page, and we click on 'Home' for example in the primary menu, the URL in the browser becomes www.webovo.nl/#hero. When we press a different section, the link doesn't change. It stays www.webovo.nl/#hero.Our menu consists of all the sections, so www.webovo.nl/#about for example.

What can we do about it? We want the URL to be www.webovo.nl when u go from the blog back to the homepage. It isn't possible to change the link to www.webovo.nl because we want the link in the menu to go to a specific section, but we don't want the www.webovo.nl/#hero to stay as the URL for the whole user session.

u can see the problem by going to webovo.nl/blog, press contact and then press a different menu link. The #contact stays in the URL.

Rick

Comment: @dliche If we do that, the link will take us to the top of the page. But we want the link to go a specific section, that is a bit further down. The problem is that if we make the link 'www.webovo.nl/#about', the link with the #about will stay in the URL box of the browser for the whole session. We don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Home link to say http://www.webovo.nl/ instead of #hero. The link locations should be editable in the admin > Appearance > Menus, or where your custom theme settings are.

Comment: If we do that, the link will take us to the top of the page. But we want the link to go a specific section, that is a bit further down. The problem is that if we make the link 'www.webovo.nl/#about', the link with the #about will stay in the URL box of the browser for the whole session. We don't want that

Comment: u can see this by going to https://www.webovo.nl/blog/, then press contact and then press a different menu link. the #contact stays in the URL

Comment: I see.. Can you open this file:
https://www.webovo.nl/wp-content/themes/onepress/assets/js/theme.js?ver=1.2.9
go to the "//Navigation Click to section" function and remove the preventDefault()? I guess the click that does the automatic scrolling stops links being followed.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the # from the URL completely? By removing PreventDefault(); the section name comes after webovo.nl, but we want the URL to stay webovo.nl no matter what menu link u click on..